# Edit the session inside Django form_valid gives "Object is not JSON serializable"

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-validation

I'm using class based views in Django to create an entry in db. I want the saved object to be stored in `session`, so that it could be passed to the next view. My view looks like

```
class CreateCommission(BaseContext, CreateView):
    # boring staff...
    model = Commissions

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.request.session['created_object'] = object
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This raise an `Object of type Commissions is not JSON serializable` error.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: You cannot store a Django model instance as JSON, because, just like the error says, it is not possible to convert an instance to JSON. Look for other ways; maybe store just the instance PK in the session.

Comment: Also, please don't use Python built-ins as variable names; `object` is already defined so you shouldn't use that as a variable name.

Comment: Thank you @Ralf, using the id works properly. (actually I didn't use `object` as a variable inside my real code. It was just an esemplification)